# Using plot3 with function with two output variables

Tags: matlab

I created a map of a U.S state on matlab and I have created a function that takes two input values (latitude,longitude) and will give back the coords (x,y) on my map. Now i want to mark specific latitudes and longitudes using the plot3 command and put a black circle on those x,y coords.

The problem i am having is i am not sure how to use a plot3 with a function that gives two outputs x = something y= something

How can this be done?
I originally thought it could be done by doing something like:
plot3(function(latitude,longitude))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a 3D plot? If not, then just use plot.

```
[x, y] = function(lat, long);
plot(x,y);
```

If your plot is 3D, then you need three inputs for plot3.

```
plot3(x,y,z)
```

Comment: That is perfect, thank you. Quick question if i may: How can i put a black circle at those locations (it is 3D so im going to adjust my function to give me 3 outputs x,y,z)

Comment: plot(x,y,z,'o','MarkerFaceColor','k','MarkerEdgeColor','k')

Answer (score 0):

Try capturing your x and y coords as variables first, then pass them to plot:

```
[x, y] = function(lat, long);
plot3(x,y);
```